# Show last seen in the little user info box

Tags: feature-request, last-seen

Could we have the last-seen info as hover info (`title` attribute) on the the little box that shows a user's info at the end of a question or answer?

[image]

It would be useful when quickly looking to see if a user is likely to have seen a comment or an answer without having to go to their profile page.

Comment: You can have something like that with [SOX](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox). But I don't believe it would be good to have it available as default. Deemphasizing stalking features is good, IMO.

Comment: @yivi Ooh, SOX looks interesting. Thanks for the link.

Comment: It also works the other way: people have the ability to know when someone did not respond to a comment or do an edit, etc. etc. The temptation to demand answers through a comment (and thus cause friction) will be great with that kind of information available.

Comment: @Gimby The information is already available - you just have to click on the link and wait for the page to load.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[@yivi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1426539/yivi) hit the nail on the head:

> Deemphasizing stalking features is good, IMO.

The following happened to me yesterday:

[image]

I presume they got that information from my profile so making it easier to view that information might just make these incidents regular occurrences.

> It would be useful when quickly looking to see if a user is likely to have seen a comment or an answer without having to go to their profile page.

But why would that be useful?

Say the user has been online and has viewed your post/comment (though, they might be online but might not have read your post/comment) but not responded, wouldn't that just leave you feeling more confused ('*Why haven't they responded if they've seen it?*')?

I see no benefit in adding this feature.

Comment: So would you say it would be better to blur the last seen information on the profile page, to maybe a day of resolution?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't know about that, that'd probably be another discussion entirely. As for this FR, IMHO, it wouldn't do us much good.

Comment: It does not confuse me. If they can't have read something since I posted it, I can put thinking about it on the back burner. I'll accept your answer as I didn't think about childish behaviour.